# Why does grep returns a non-zero value when there is a HIT?

Tags: grep, centos

Why does grep returns a non-zero value when there is a HIT?

Aren't non-zero values supposed to be for unsuccessful command executions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what you can find in the [man page of the grep command](https://ss64.com/bash/grep.html) :

```
Exit Status grep exits with one of the following values:
0 One or more lines were selected.
1 No lines were selected.
>1 An error occurred - syntax error in pattern, inaccessible input files, or other system error. In other words a failure to find a matching item is reported as an error (1)

The '-v' option can be used to effectively invert the exit status.
```

So, there are several answers to your question depending on the command you entered. If you want more help, edit your post with the complete command / process used.